# Spring social returning wrong user profile

Tags: spring, spring-social, spring-social-linkedin

I'm using Spring Social LinkedIn to retrieve user profiles with a custom ConnectController since I want to the user to login and retrieve the profile in one step. The issue is that sometimes the first user in the system is returned instead of the currently logged in user.

Here is my CustomConnectController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/connect")
public class CustomConnectController extends ConnectController {

    @Inject
    public CustomConnectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
            ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        super(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
    }

    @Override
    protected String connectView(String providerId) {
        return "redirect:/hey/" + providerId + "Connect";
    }

    @Override
    protected String connectedView(String providerId) {
        return "redirect:/hey/" + providerId + "Connected";
    }
    }
```

and my webcontroller

```
@Controller
public class WebController {    

    @Autowired
    private LinkedIn linkedin;

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionRepository repository;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/hey/linkedinConnected", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String linkedinConnected(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, Locale locale) {
        if (repository.findConnections("linkedin").isEmpty()
                || !linkedin.isAuthorized()) {
            return "redirect:/connect/linkedin";
        }
        LinkedInProfile userProfile = linkedin.profileOperations().getUserProfile();
        return "loggedinpage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hey/linkedinConnect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String linkedinConnect(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, Locale locale) {
        if (repository.findConnections("linkedin").isEmpty()
                || !linkedin.isAuthorized()) {
            return "redirect:/connect/linkedin";
        }
        LinkedInProfile userProfile = linkedin.profileOperations().getUserProfile();
        return "loggedinpage";
    }

}
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?